# random php multi-dimensional array and get the original array index

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Anyone can help me about multi dimensional arrays? I have an array that wanted to random arrays inside it, so therefore its hierarchy or there index value will be changed and different from the original arrangement of arrays, like:

This is the original arrays

```
Array(
    [0]=>Array(
             [title]       => 'Title 1'
             [description] => 'description here'
         )
    [1]=>Array(
             [title]       => 'Title 2'
             [description] => 'another description here'           
         )
    [2]=>Array(
             [title]       => 'Title Here Again'
             [description] => 'description here again'           
         )
)
```

That will be the original structure of the array above, and if you random it, let say this will be the outcome

This is the random-ed arrays

```
 Array(
        [0]=>Array(
                 [title]       => 'Title 2'
                 [description] => 'another description here'
             )
        [1]=>Array(
                 [title]       => 'Title 3'
                 [description] => 'another description again'           
             )
        [2]=>Array(
                 [title]       => 'Title 1'
                 [description] => 'description here'          
             )
    )
```

As you can see, values inside the arrays are being randomize at different positions, now the problem is i can't get the exact logic on how to get the original array index like this -> ( [0] ) from randomized arrays. Like the value 'Title 1' its original index is [0], and after it was random-ed it became [2] but still i wanted 'Title 1' being assigned to index [0]. Here's a short php code on how i randomized the arrays:

```
foreach (shuffleThis($rss->getItems()) as $item) {

    foreach($item as $key=>$value){
        if($key=='title'){
                $title=$value;
        }
        if($key=='description'){
            $description=$value;    
        }
    }
}
function shuffleThis($list) { 
  if (!is_array($list)) return $list; 

  $keys = array_keys($list); 
  shuffle($keys); 
  $random = array(); 
  foreach ($keys as $key) { 
    $random[] = $list[$key]; 
  }
  return $random; 
}
```

Just wanted to get they `key`s original array index from being random-ed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to change the *order* of the elements but preserve the keys. You can do that with a small modification:

```
function shuffleThis($list) { 
    if (!is_array($list)) return $list; 

    $keys = array_keys($list); 
    shuffle($keys); 
    $random = array(); 
    foreach ($keys as $key) { 
        $random[$key] = $list[$key]; // CHANGE HERE that preserves the keys
    }
    return $random; 
}
```

Comment: Wow! this is a great answer, when i tried it, i can see that the elements are changing in position but not the array keys. But how would i able to get the key index number like this [0], the zero inside?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. How to get which key, and given what information?

Answer (score 1):

Use strings as keys and function 'shuffle'.
Example of shuffling: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php#104430