# Find array key who has the least number of children

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1363
            [1] => 1364
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 1079
            [6] => 1366
            [7] => 37
            [8] => 1398
        )

    [1363] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1364
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 1079
            [7] => 1366
            [8] => 1398
        )

    [1364] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1363
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 1366
            [7] => 37
            [8] => 1398
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1363
            [2] => 1364
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 1079
            [6] => 1366
            [7] => 37
            [8] => 1398
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1363
            [1] => 1364
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 1079
            [6] => 1366
            [7] => 37
            [8] => 1398
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1363
            [2] => 1364
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 1079
            [6] => 1366
            [7] => 37
            [8] => 1398
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1363
            [2] => 1364
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 4
            [6] => 1079
            [7] => 1366
            [8] => 37
        )

    [1079] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1363
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 1366
            [7] => 37
            [8] => 1398
        )

    [1366] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1363
            [2] => 1364
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 4
            [6] => 2
            [7] => 1079
            [8] => 37
            [9] => 1398
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1364
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 1079
            [7] => 1366
            [8] => 1398
        )

    [1398] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1363
            [2] => 1364
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 4
            [6] => 1079
            [7] => 1366
            [8] => 37
        )

)
```

I want to return the key of the array which has the least number of children. In this case, any key that 9 values in the subarray. This will be part of a while loop and the array will lose a value in the loop. So the 2nd time, most will have 8 values, then 7 and so on...

**UPDATE:**

I made this:

```
        $arrPotentialPicksTemp = array();

        foreach ($arrPotentialPicks as $id => $picks) {
            $arrPotentialPicksTemp[$id] = count($picks);
        }
```

But I'm stuck.

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: I was thinking of doing a foreach and create another array with the counts. But is there a  shorter way?

Comment: You should start with what you think, and if someone have a better solution you will get it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php

$array = []; // Your array

$minNumber =  min(array_map(function($subarray) {
    return count($subarray);
}, $array));

echo $minNumber;
```

`array_map` applies a callback to each element of an array (`$array`) in our case. So, this anonymous function:

```
function($subarray) {
    return count($subarray);
}
```

returns total number of elements of each element of the parent array.
Thus

```
array_map(function($subarray) {
    return count($subarray);
}, $array)
```

returns an array, where each element is a count of elements of subarray.

Then we apply `min` function, which returns the minumum value of an array. Simple.

EDIT

Since you need the *key* of the element with least number of elements:

```
$array = [
    'foo' =>[1, 3, 4, 5],
    'bar' => [1, 3],
    'baz' => [1],
];


// So here is proper, readable version:

$counted = array_map(function($subarray) {
    return count($subarray);
}, $array);

// print_r($counted) outputs
// Array ( [foo] => 4 [bar] => 2 [baz] => 1 )
// So we have keys and element counters as values

// Now let's flip arrays and keys


$flipped = array_flip($counted);

// print_r($counted) outputs 
// Array ( [4] => 'foo' [2] => 'bar' [1]=> 'baz' )
// So we have keys and element counters as values

// Now let's find the minimum key, which will have the final result

$lowestKey = min(array_keys($flipped));

echo $flipped[$lowestKey];
```

Comment: Nice, but I need the key of the array with min value. Not the value itself.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that makes things more interesting.

Comment: I made this:

<code>
            $arrPotentialPicksTemp = array();

            foreach ($arrPotentialPicks as $id => $picks) {
                $arrPotentialPicksTemp[$id] = count($picks);
            }
</code>
But I'm stuck.

Comment: I've updated the answer so you get the key of the element with least elements in it.

Comment: doesn't quite work since the flipped result is: Array ( [9] => 1398 [10] => 1366 )

Comment: @jesse94, you are right, sorry, I'm way to hasty. I've updated the code, one step was missing: `min(array_keys($flipped))` returns the minimum key (which is subarray elements count), so we need to `echo $flipped[$lowestKey];` to output the very key we're looking for. Sorry again; I've tested this one.

Comment: Is there a way to randomize the keys with equal values so I don't always get the same key with lowest count?

Comment: found this to do so: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346633/random-php-multi-dimensional-array-and-get-the-original-array-index)